# What if you blocked every sweat gland in your body?

Tags: sweat

I have really sweaty hands, so I decided to put Driclor on it. However, once my hands got dry, my armpits started sweating like crazy. My doctor said this is due to compensatory sweating. So I was wondering, what would happen if you completely blocked every sweat gland on your body(not that I'm going to)? Would you explode or something?

Comment: It was only a matter of time before somebody asked a question answered by a James Bond movie. http://www.snopes.com/movies/films/goldfinger.asp

Comment: @CareyGregory Care to post an answer with the link? That’s basically all we need.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's speculation and not a health issue